# tooltip like control on the div

Tags: css

does anyone know how to create a tooltip on the div. On my page, i have 4 div and I want every time  the user mouse over on a div, it will show down the tooltip from the top and after few seconds the tooltip will be automatically hidden..

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the title attribute:

`<div id="myDiv" title="My Tool Tip Text here">Div Stuff</div>`

Or take a look at this (A javascript example, does not automatically hide, but could be easily modified to do so):

http://djgdesign.co.uk/display.php?id=47

Comment: Hi All.. sorry for the confusion.. it will be something on the image when you mouse over it you can see the caption (please refer to http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/ and go to "with caption & links" section. But instead of on the image how can i implement it on the div

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript and JQuery it's pretty simple, take a look at

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/ for example

Doing it in pure html and css would be more complicated. You could play with :hover, absolute
positioning and z-index to achieve it.

Comment: Hi All.. sorry for the confusion.. it will be something on the image when you mouse over it you can see the caption (please refer to http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/ and go to "with caption & links" section. But instead of on the image how can i implement it on the div

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the [TipTip jQuery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) its very easy to adapt and also easy to extend. Ask if you need help with this.

Comment: Hi All.. sorry for the confusion.. it will be something on the image when you mouse over it you can see the caption (please refer to http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/ and go to "with caption & links" section. But instead of on the image how can i implement it on the div